Convergence in $^1$ and continuos CDF , implies converges in $^1$ for the corresponding binarized succession?
Let $X_n$ a succession of random variables with $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{P}(X_n=x)>0\} \subseteq[0,1]$ $\forall n$, and X a random variable with $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{P}(X=x)>0\} \subseteq[0,1]$ and continuos CDF.
If $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\rightarrow 0$, is it true that $\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(X_n)-\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(X)|]\rightarrow 0$?
Where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function, equal to 1 if the argument is in $[0,1]$, 0 otherwise.
[Progresses] @user6247850 suggested here to combine the fact that $^1$ convergence implies convergence in distribution and the Portmanteau theorem. Still, it is unclear to me how to combine the two to get the thesis.
